# How to get TImestamp type in Firebase functions in typescript?

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to use firebase Timestamp type in a type declaration for firestore document field, but cannot figure out where I can import. Does anybody know?

My code.

```js
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

interface MyDocument {
  timestamp1: admin.firestore.Timestamp,
  timestamp2: functions.firestore.Timestamp,
}
```

Error in timestamp1: `Cannot find namespace 'admin'.ts(2503)`
Error in timestamp2: `Namespace '"/path/to/project/functions/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/firestore"' has no exported member 'Timestamp'.`

package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    ...
    "firebase-admin": "^9.5.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.13.1",
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me in my Typescript project:

```
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
let t : admin.firestore.Timestamp = //....
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's the shorthand notation:

```
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
import Timestamp = admin.firestore.Timestamp;
```

Answer (score 1):

Importing like this is the only way it worked for me:

```
import { Timestamp } from "firebase-admin/firestore";
```

```
"dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^11.11.0",
    ...
},
```